# Openvpn make computer on local network accessible

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to make computes on local network accessible for VPN clients. My server is available on `10.0.2.1` from VPN but I can't connect to other computers on local network of the server. How can I do this? Server has internal IP address on network `192.168.2.163` and I want connect to `192.168.2.182` from VPN.

```
    mode server
    port 27015
    proto tcp-server
    tls-server
    dev tap0
    ##dev tun0

    ifconfig 10.0.2.1 255.255.255.0
    ifconfig-pool 10.0.2.100 10.0.2.105 255.255.255.0
    duplicate-cn

    ca /etc/openvpn/cert/cacert.pem
    cert /etc/openvpn/cert/cert.pem
    key /etc/openvpn/cert/key.pem
    dh /etc/openvpn/cert/dh1024.pem

    log-append /var/log/openvpn
    status /tmp/vpn.status 10

    user root
    group root
    comp-lzo
    verb 3

    keepalive 1 220
```

netstat:

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tap0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the must-haves are in place (the server is happy to forward traffic, it has no `iptables` rules preventing this), then as with every IP conversation, there are two important traffic directing steps that must be taken: the client must know that it should use the VPN tunnel to talk to the remote system, and the remote system must know that it should use the VPN tunnel to reply.

The former is achieved by telling your openvpn server to advertise a route to the office network, to the clients, with the following statement in server's `openvpn.conf`:

```
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
```

The latter is achieved **either** by having all the remote systems use the openvpn server as their default gateway **or** by setting routes back to the openvpn address space via the server.  Assuming that the remote openvpn server is not already the office default gateway, the route can be set by doing

```
route add -net 10.0.2.0/24 gw 192.168.2.163
```

on the server `192.168.2.182`.